# Model breaks at high velocities

Tags: control, gazebo, gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello Guys,

i am rebuilding the azcar car model from here: http://cps-vo.org/node/25319/browser

But for some reason with my own controllers and added steering joints for the rear. My model breaks at high speeds!

- Meaning that the rear steering joints waver around the z axis, but are not fixed on it anymore.

I have implemented the "rear axle motor" as a velocitycontroller. Has sb. experienced sth. similar.
I am currently thinking, that my mass distribution is wrong. But i couldnt find anything regarding that topic.

Thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14425/model-breaks-at-high-velocities/) by [Franzisdrak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2821/franzisdrak/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Fixed by adjusting the different inertias and mass ratio.

---

Originally posted by [Franzisdrak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2821/franzisdrak/) with karma: 43 on 2016-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1